# Difference between $() and $(document).ready()

Tags: jquery

What's the difference between :

```
$(function() { ... });
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

and what mean this $() ?

Comment: Both are same, $(function()) was introduced later with upgraded version of jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the docs http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> ```
> $( document ).ready(function() {
>   // Handler for .ready() called.
> });
> ```
>
> Which is equivalent to calling:
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>   // Handler for .ready() called.
> });
> ```

---

`$` is just a variable name / shortcut for `jQuery`

so you're basically calling the function `jQuery()` and passing some parameters to it or calling it's methods

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two, the first one is the alias for the second one.